# How to split comma seperated text value ('26148770-2-1-1-3, 20202228-2-0-1-2') and move to next line if morethen one comma values in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

How to split comma seperated text value ('26148770-2-1-1-3, 20202228-2-0-1-2') and move to next line if morethen one comma values, how to set auto height for that row if it has more then one values after split in ag-grid?

```
export columns [
    {
        field: 'apple',
        headerName: 'Apple Number',
        headerTooltip: 'Apple Number'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated column definition using `autoHeight`, `valueGetter`, `cellStyle`, `wrapText`:

```
export columns [
   {
        autoHeight: true, // added to update height based on value after split comma seperated value
        cellStyle: { 'white-space': 'pre' }, // move new value to next line
        field: 'appleNumber',
        headerName: 'Apple Number',
        headerTooltip: 'Apple Number',
        valueGetter: ({ data }) => !isEmpty(data.appleNumber) ? data.appleNumber?.replaceAll(',', '\n') : '', // '\n' to insert a new line
        wrapText: true // wrap text
   }
]
```